# Is there any efficient way to have a case insensitive string as a HashMap key?

Tags: hashmap, rust, case-insensitive

I'm trying to count number of times a word appears in a text. I'm using `HashMap` and my implementation ignores case. I achieve that by converting all words to lowercase:

```
for line in reader.lines() {
    for mut curr in line.as_ref().unwrap().split_whitespace() {
        match word_map.entry(curr.to_string().to_lowercase()) {
            Entry::Occupied(entry) => {
                *entry.into_mut() += 1;
            }
            Entry::Vacant(entry) => {
                entry.insert(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to consider "the" and "The" same, but if "the" doesn't appear just hold "The" in the `HashMap`. Right now, I hold all words in lowercase. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: What should happen if the text contains The, THE and the

Comment: They will be all considered as the same and whichever version first found should be stored. The problem with mine is even when there is no "the" in text, but there is only "The", it is stored as all lower case, not in original form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to use [`UniCase`](https://docs.rs/unicase) as a key:

```
use unicase::UniCase;

type Words = std::collections::HashMap<UniCase, u32>;
```

If I understand their documentation, `UniCase::new("The")` stores the actual string `"The"` in it, but if you compare it with `Unicase::new("the")`, you will see that it is the same string.

Comment: I don't think that crate implements correct caseless comparisons because I don't see any normalization happening. The `caseless` crate does it correctly (but has a different API, so there might be some trade offs between them): https://docs.rs/caseless/0.2.0/caseless/

Comment: @BurntSushi5 Hum, I saw `assert_eq!(UniCase::new("Maße"), UniCase::new("MASSE"));` and I though that it proves enough that caseless comparison is ok.

Comment: @Boiethios I think BurntSushi5's point is that the concept of comparison is way more complicated than `UniCase` is designed to handle. For example, this fails: `assert_eq!(UniCase::new("Åström"), UniCase::new("Åström")` (make sure you copy it exactly). The crate doesn't handle normalization of precomposed / non-composed Unicode text, as one example.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you for the explanation. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: For that specific example, that's a [precomposed character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character). However, Unicode [normalization](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) is a larger topic that I'm not well-versed to speak on.

Comment: @Shepmaster The maintainer of this crate should see this question. If I don't forget, I will open an issue in the Github.